# Migrating a question to another SE site

Tags: discussion, migration

I was just tempted to vote to migrate a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059643) from stackoverflow to [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). However it seems only possible to migrate to superuser or serverfault.

Is there a good reason why migrating to other sites is not a good idea?

Comment: Thanks, seems like this has been discussed before - without any result. :( This means a migration is currently not possible at all?

Comment: @michas: It still is possible, but requires a specific "moderator attention" flag, where you request the target site.

Comment: Only solution is a custom flag with text "migrate to crypto.se" or something similar. I've flagged many questions that way. The big downside is that it takes days to weeks for the migration to happen, depending on how overworked the SO mods are.

Comment: The question does seem on-topic for SO.  Maybe it could have been better asked on crypto (I'm not familiar so I'm just guessing), but migration is only supposed to be for good questions that are off-topic on the existing site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The migration paths available in the "close and migrate" dialog are occasionally re-assessed and adjusted. The current paths reflect the highest number and percentage of successful migrations.

If the site you want to migrate to is not available in the list, your option at that point is to flag the question and use the "Other" option to make your case. *If* a Moderator agrees with your argument they'll migrate the question.

Note:

- The first rule of migrating: "Don't migrate crap." Being on-topic on the other site is not enough; it must be an outstanding question that just happens to be in the wrong place
- Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, not even by a Moderator
- There can be quite a bit of overlap among some sites. If a question is on-topic on its current site it won't be migrated, even it it might be "more" on-topic on the proposed target.